# Tessellation transition

Tags: graphics, terrain, tessellation

I want to implement tessellation transition from fine to coarse geometry and vice versa for terrain rendering which doesn't introduce discontinuities (cracks).
Real-time performance is not required i.e. it can be view-independent.

What do you think about the following proposal:

[alt text http://www.shrani.si/f/A/qD/2UJlczki/tessellation.png](http://www.shrani.si/f/A/qD/2UJlczki/tessellation.png)?

1. Is it even possible?
2. Have you implemented something similar?
3. What are the drawbacks?
4. Do you have any simpler suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this has been done many times. See for instance [Hierarchical 4-K Meshes](http://w3.impa.br/~lvelho/h4k/h4.html). There are probably references that are specific to terrain modeling and rendering but I don't have one handy.